# I'm trying to count how many transfers took more than 30 minutes, and this error keeps showing up

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is the formula I wrote ↓

```
count(if(avg(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date,request_datetime,minute)),0) >= 30,id,NULL)
```

And this is the error that keeps showing up↓

> No matching signature for function IF for argument types: FLOAT64,
>   INT64. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) at [10:10]

Comment: read your parenthesis

Comment: I am not much aware of bigquery, but like any sql you can use where clause, and select required column . In your case count(*) should also work.

Comment: @PaganottiFelipeSato . . . Your code looks like it is nesting aggregation functions `count()` and `avg()`.  This is not generally allowed in any database.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with this construct.

First, what is the `,0)`.  It doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you intend:

```
count(if(avg(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date, request_datetime, minute
                           )
            ) >= 30,
         id,   -- then
         NULL  -- else
     )
```

More importantly, you are nesting aggregation functions and that is not allowed.  One possibility is that you do not intent the `avg()` at all, but only want to look at the values within a single row.  This can also be simplified, using `countif()`:

```
countif(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date, request_datetime, minute
                      ) >= 30
       )
```

I am guessing that this is what you really want.

Comment: Sir Gordon Linoff thank you for your answer. It worked.

Comment: @PaganottiFelipeSato . . . I would suggest that you accept this (or another) answer if your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "Why is this happening?":

```
IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY)
```

requires three parameters. You're only giving it two. This is how it's processed:

```
count(if(
         avg(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date,request_datetime,minute)),  <-- This is not a BOOL
         0  <-- This is the second parameter to if
         ) >= 30,  <-- This is a BOOL as the first parameter to count
      id,  <-- This is a second parameter to count
      NULL) <-- This is the third parameter to count
```

Try this (Disclaimer: Not tested):

```
count(if(avg(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date,request_datetime,minute)) >= 30,
         1,
         NULL)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF` statement needs a `boolean` expression.You closed the parenthesis in the wrong place as you can see below, and it caused the IF argument to be a `FLOAT` (AVG result) and not the expression `AVG(...) >= 30` as you expected.

```
count(
    if(
       avg(
           timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date,request_datetime,minute)
          )
      ,0
      ) >= 30,id,NULL)
```

What you're probably trying to do is:

```
count(
    if(
      avg(timestamp_diff(broker_delivery_date,request_datetime,minute)) >= 30
      ,id,NULL
      )
 )
```